# Custom Javascript Search that eliminates elements that don't match search parameters

Tags: javascript, function, search

So I am trying to create a search function on a page that is filled with links separated into different sections to make it easier for people to find a particular link they are looking for by eliminating all information that doesn't pertain to what they are looking for.

I want the search to change elements that don't match the search parameters to "display:none;" however I can't seem to figure out how to make a section whose list items are "display:none;" to also "display:none;" so that section no longer appears if it does not contain the parameters of the search.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearch()" 
placeholder="Search this page!">
<div id="content">
<section class="parent">
                <h2>heading two</h2>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">list item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">list item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <section class="parent">
                <h2>heading two</h2>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">list item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">list item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
</section>
</div>

<script>
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, parentDivs, children;
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("content");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
sect = ul.getElementsByTagName('section');
parentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
children = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  li[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  li[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Are the sections labelled parent dynamically added from somewhere outside the script?

Comment: No they are not. Sorry I didn't see this question earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a slight modification of your code so that it will go through all of the parent divs and get the `childNodes` then proceed to loop through all of those while using a counter `c` if it counts to the same length as the list of elements it will also then set that div to `display:none`.

```
 function mySearch() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, parentDivs, children;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("content");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  sect = ul.getElementsByTagName('section');
  parentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
  children = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

  if (filter.length > 3) {
  console.log(filter.length);
    for (var x = 0; x < parentDivs.length; x++) {
            parentDivs[x].style.display = "";
    }
  }

  for (var p = 0; p < parentDivs.length; p++) {
    var c = 0;
    var nodes = parentDivs[p].childNodes[3].getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

      var a = nodes[i].querySelectorAll("a");

      if (a[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        nodes[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        nodes[i].style.display = "none";
        c++;
      }
    }

    if (c === nodes.length) {
      parentDivs[p].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle with my answer https://jsfiddle.net/nq7Lfz1o/5/ It is using `"TEXT"` as a filter rather than input to show the solution.This also includes a reset so you can go back to a state where everything is shown if the length is above 3.

Comment: There's a chance this could be wrong as you didn't include your onkeyup event with your original code, let me know and if it doesn't we can rework this answer to meet your goals.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I just had function mySearch{} around that code. However I put your code in, but for some reason i keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: nodes[i].getElementsByTagName is not a function. It's having problem with the line: a = nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

Comment: I have updated my answer with a slightly different solution as I noticed the childNodes weren't returning as expected, give this a whirl.

Comment: The function works now however, it's still not setting the section to "display: none;". Here I have uploaded it to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nq7Lfz1o/1/

Comment: This probably isn't the desired final solution but https://jsfiddle.net/nq7Lfz1o/2/ but does what was intended. Going to quickly add in resets.

Comment: here is an example with a simple reset https://jsfiddle.net/nq7Lfz1o/4/

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tyris_Phoenix Close,if you change the reset to `>` rather than `<` you'll be all fixed. updating answer. Also if I've solved your problem feel free to mark this as correct :-)